# Can I use GAIM (Pidgin) to telnet (for MOOs, MUSHes, MUDs, etc) like TF?

Tags: telnet, pidgin

GAIM supports many protocols, but I couldn't find a way to create a 
'telnet' account, so that I can finally stop using TinyFugue to play 
MUDs/etc.

How do I create a telnet "account" with GAIM? Do one of the other 
protocols secretly support telnet? Can I create a local 
jabber-to-telnet proxy or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Jabber Telnet Bot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jabbertelnetbot/) that is bot that provides jabber to telnet gateway. Project is little old, and I was unable to run in successfully, but there is a chance that it will run on another configurations.

After downloading package you need to modify configuration in `cfg/jbtelbot.conf` file to set host where you want to connect and Jabber account on which bot will be running. After that bot should ready to start. One big disadvantage is that when you want to change telnet host you need to edit config file and restart bot.

For me idea of running telnet inside IM to play MUDs is little weird - better solution will be use dedicated MUD client like [TinyFugue](http://tinyfugue.sourceforge.net/) that was mentioned. As I can see TinyFugue is unmaintained right now, but there is still developed client [TinTin++](http://tintin.sourceforge.net/) that offers [long list of features](http://tintin.sourceforge.net/features.php) including session logging, command history and scripts.

Comment: I meant to approve this earlier, sorry. I want to keep all my "chats" in a single window w/ tabs, instead of having different non-Pidgin/GAIM programs for irc, telnet, etc. I also couldn't get Jabber Telnet Bot to compile, but this was the most helpful answer and does give me some direction.